# Is this definition of a universal set correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Jay Cummings (2021, *Proofs: A Long-Form Mathematics Textbook*, p. 83):

[image]

So if for example $A=\{1,2\}$, $U_1=\{1,2,3\}$, and $U_2=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both universal sets of $A$? So what's the complement of $A$?

Comment: This is a weird definition. A universal set is fixed in some context and then you take all complements with respect to it. Normally people don’t define the term at all-it’s an informal way to refer to the general domain of discourse.

Comment: @KevinArlin: OK so it's not wrong but just weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book says that *the complement of $A$ **in** $U$ is $U \setminus A$*.

So, the complement of $\{1,2\}$ **in** $\{1,2,3\}$ is $\{3\}$, while the complement of $\{1,2\}$ **in** $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $\{3,4\}$.